# Data.table selecting columns by name, e.g. using grepl

Tags: r, data.table

Say I have the following data.table:

```
dt <- data.table("x1"=c(1:10), "x2"=c(1:10),"y1"=c(10:1),"y2"=c(10:1), desc = c("a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","c","c"))
```

I want to sum columns starting with an 'x', and sum columns starting with an 'y', by desc. At the moment I do this by:

```
dt[,.(Sumx=sum(x1,x2), Sumy=sum(y1,y2)), by=desc]
```

which works, but I would like to refer to all columns with "x" or "y" by their column names, eg using grepl().

Please could you advise me how to do so? I think I need to use with=FALSE, but cannot get it to work in combination with by=desc?

Answer (score 2):

*One-liner:*

```
melt(dt, id="desc", measure.vars=patterns("^x", "^y"), value.name=c("x","y"))[, 
  lapply(.SD, sum), by=desc, .SDcols=x:y]
```

*Long version (by @Frank):*

First, you probably don't want to store your data like that. Instead...

```
m = melt(dt, id="desc", measure.vars=patterns("^x", "^y"), value.name=c("x","y"))

    desc variable  x  y
 1:    a        1  1 10
 2:    a        1  2  9
 3:    a        1  3  8
 4:    b        1  4  7
 5:    b        1  5  6
 6:    b        1  6  5
 7:    b        1  7  4
 8:    b        1  8  3
 9:    c        1  9  2
10:    c        1 10  1
11:    a        2  1 10
12:    a        2  2  9
13:    a        2  3  8
14:    b        2  4  7
15:    b        2  5  6
16:    b        2  6  5
17:    b        2  7  4
18:    b        2  8  3
19:    c        2  9  2
20:    c        2 10  1
```

Then you can do...

```
setnames(m[, lapply(.SD, sum), by=desc, .SDcols=x:y], 2:3, paste0("Sum", c("x", "y")))[]
#   desc Sumx Sumy
#1:    a   12   54
#2:    b   60   50
#3:    c   38    6
```

For more on improving the data structure you're working with, read about [tidying data](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v059i10).

Comment: @Frank No thanks for the edit. I was in the process of editing.

Comment: @Frank It's fine, you made some valuable edits.  I thought to add `setnames` to change it to OP's expected.

Comment: Yes, how to structure my data is still a learning curve! Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

Use `mget` with `grep` is an option, where `grep("^x", ...)` returns the column names starting with `x` and use `mget` to get the column data, `unlist` the result and then you can calculate the `sum`:

```
dt[,.(Sumx=sum(unlist(mget(grep("^x", names(dt), value = T)))), 
      Sumy=sum(unlist(mget(grep("^y", names(dt), value = T))))), by=desc]

#   desc Sumx Sumy
#1:    a   12   54
#2:    b   60   50
#3:    c   38    6
```